# Is it possible to install multi node OpenStack using Juju without using MAAS?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm quite new to Juju and MAAS. Is it possible to install OpenStack using Juju on multiple nodes without MAAS? Can anyone refer me to any guide or post regarding this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MAAS is recommended, since Juju and MAAS work quite well together and a simple

```
juju add-machine
```

can requisition a machine for you from the MAAS pool.

That being said, if you prefer not to use MAAS, 
https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/clouds-manual
will guide you on how to add nodes manually via SSH, thereby working around the MAAS reccommendation.

You can then deploy Openstack charms directly to the individual nodes.